# Finding latitude and longitude of a known place using api?

Tags: java, google-maps, location

Is there a way by which I can find latitude  and longitude of a known place e.g. known city like Singapore, Kuala Lumpur / New York.

Comment: They're down right now, but I like [getlatlon.com](http://getlatlon.com/)

Comment: Right now: http://getlatlon.yohman.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geocoding

Check out: [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Answer (score 1):

Ask google.
e.g.

This http request:
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=Singapore

returns:

```
{
  "name": "Singapore",
  "Status": {
    "code": 200,
    "request": "geocode"
  },
  "Placemark": [ {
    "id": "p1",
    "address": "Singapur",
    "AddressDetails": {
   "Accuracy" : 1,
   "Country" : {
      "CountryName" : "Singapur",
      "CountryNameCode" : "SG"
   }
},
    "ExtendedData": {
      "LatLonBox": {
        "north": 1.4708809,
        "south": 1.1663980,
        "east": 104.0856805,
        "west": 103.6056246
      }
    },
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": [ 103.8198360, 1.3520830, 0 ]
    }
  } ]
}
```